# How to resolve promise when applying [style.background-image]

Tags: angular

I have a div like this:

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' getImageFunction() ')'">
</div>
```

The problem is `getImageFunction()` returns a promise. How do I resolve the promise to get the image url?

I tried doing this but obviously didn't work

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{getImageFunction() | async}}');">
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it'd be possible doing some like [**this**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBPC2lyYGrXE9VczSCcw), but I really don't recommend this approach. This function will be called indefinitely... it's really better to assign the promise to a variable and do something like [**this**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ipHzlKbt5feOkaKWNDrN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest to keep it simple with variable. As async call are called indefinitely as @developer033 said and which is correct

Can handle it simpliy with a variable

```
<div [style]="showUrl ? background-image: url('demo.jpg') : null ">
</div>
```

and in `.ts` handle for bool value `showUrl`

```
this.getImageFunction().then(() => {
   this.showUrl = true;
}, () => {
   this.showUrl = false;
})
```